# Javascript to disable inline onclick for element loaded as asp.net control

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Webforms page. In the code-behind, an `onclick` attribute is added to a label control and a textbox control using the code -

```
lblName.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:location.href='NameForm.aspx?id=" & CStr(fnRetRow("name_id")) & "';")
txtName.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:location.href='NameForm.aspx?id=" & CStr(fnRetRow("name_id")) & "';")
```

The following HTML elements are generated. (Note, these are ultimately located within several nested layers of `<table><tr>`... elements on the page.) -

```
<td class="formlabel">
  <span id="lblName" class="formlabel" onclick="javascript:location.href='NameForm.aspx?id=123';"></span>
</td>
<td class="forminputtxt">
  <input id="txtName" class="forminputtxt" onclick="javascript:location.href='NameForm.aspx?id=123';">
</td>
```

**QUESTION:** How can I use a simple JavaScript function in the aspx page to disable these `onclick` attributes after the page loads (or elements loaded) ?

I've tried the following options without success -

```
<script language = "javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('lblName').onclick = '';    // option 1 for label
    document.getElementById('txtName').onclick = '';    // option 1 for textbox

    document.getElementById('lblName').removeAttribute("onclick");  //option 2 for label
    document.getElementById('txtName').removeAttribute("onclick");  // option 2 for textbox
  }
</script>
```

Option 2 has no effect. Option 1 for the textbox has no effect.

Option 1 for the label does somehow disable the link; however, the inline javascript is still displayed in the final HTML of the page. This is acceptable, but not ideal.

What is a simple way to disable (or ideally remove) both `onclick` attributes after page load?

NOTE: JQuery is not available in the page.

Comment: Think about what you are trying to do. Is is possible to know server side whether the click events should result in the behavior defined in the onclick attribute? If clicking the elements shouldn't fire the event, it would be better to leave off the onclick attribute server side. It would make your payload a tiny bit smaller.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm seeking a quick front-end 'hack' to disable the `onclick` events without altering the code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign null to both events

```
document.getElementById('lblName').onclick = null; 
document.getElementById('txtName').onclick = null;
```

It will not remove `onclick="javascript:location.href=...` from "View Source" of the page, because this is how HTML was rendered by server-side code, but it will effectively disable "onclick" event.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwE74/1/ (note that in your HTML "SPAN" tag was not closed, I corrected it for the demo)

Comment: Thank you. This, along with correcting a typo, worked to resolve my issue.